# Emit serialization of default value of value types in protobuf-net

Tags: c#, .net, protobuf-net

In my project I need not only time but also information about the UTC offset. Therefore I thought about using `DateTimeOffset` class.

I did no magic, just declared a `struct` containing the `short` for offset and `long` for ticks (same as in `DateTimeOffset`) - and of course defining the `ProtoContract` and `ProtoMember` attributes.

But: even when this value is not initialized (both fields zero) there are 2 additional bytes on the wire (I did a cross check with a `class`)!

I tried to inherit the `DefaultValueAttribute` and set *my* default value - but also to no avail.

The reason is that protobuf-net checks for the `DefaultValueAttribute` by name (in `MetaType.ApplyDefaultBehaviour(bool isEnum, ProtoMemberAttribute normalizedAttribute)`).

```
if ((attrib = GetAttribute(attribs, "System.ComponentModel.DefaultValueAttribute")) != null)
{
      object tmp;
      if(attrib.TryGet("Value", out tmp)) defaultValue = tmp;
}
```

But even if I change this, I get an exception in `DefaultValueDecorator.Read(Compiler.CompilerContext ctx, Compiler.CodeLabel label)` complaining:

```
 default:
      throw new NotSupportedException("Type cannot be represented as a default value: " 
                                     + expected.FullName);
```

Does anyone know the reason for this limitation?

Why not using default(T) for value types?